How to create a list of unqiue values from a list of multiple sheets
I've got tree planting list across multiple sheets e.g.,



Species
Column B




Hawthorn
40


Blackthorn
50



I'm trying to create a summary sheet whereby you can select projects (i.e., sheets) from a dropdown list and that will automatically generate a list of species and there totals. I've managed to do one for all the projects, but ideally would like one that has selected projects on.
I think I've figured out how to get the totals (colB) using:
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!"&"A2:A100"),A2,INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!"&"D2:D100")))

However, I cannot figure out how to get a list of unqiue trees species from the selected sheets. I've tried:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(VSTACK(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!"&"A2:A50")),VSTACK(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!"&"A2:A50"))<>""))

But this doesn't seem to work.
Here is a link to my sheet.
https://easyupload.io/dyc7ne

I think you need to use REDUCE.
Here is a Youtube video on how to stack tables into one big table using REDUCE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7c61lkkkUFw
In your case, you can use below formula:
=LET(
    results, REDUCE(
        "",
        "'" & SheetList & "'!" & "A2:A50",
        LAMBDA(stacked, row, VSTACK(stacked, INDIRECT(row)))
    ),
    UNIQUE(FILTER(results, results <> ""), FALSE, FALSE)
)



My solution for you is to consolidate data then use the pivot table.

Add "Project" column to every project sheet.

Consolidate all projects into the single table.

Insert the pivot table.

Whenever you insert new data or new project, refresh the pivot table.

Anylize your data.

Modify the pivot table per your needs.


